# How to change values in JSON array

Tags: json

I have a file that gets a json response like this:

```
{
   total": 86,
   "data": [
    {
        "Id": 2,
        "Name": "User One",
        "Shipping": 1,
        "Created": "25 March 2017"
    },
    {
        "Id": 3,
        "Name": "User Two",
        "Shipping": 2,
        "Created": "25 March 2017"
    },
    {
        "Id": 4,
        "Name": "User Three",
        "Shipping": 3,
        "Created": "26 March 2017"
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to run through this result and change all the Shipping values to:

1 Post Office

2 PostNet

3 Courier

In my code I do:

```
$.each(data.data, function () {
      $.each(this, function (key, value) {
         if(key == 'Shipping') {
             switch(value) {
               case 2:
                   ? = 'PostNet';
                   break;
               case 2:
                   ? = 'Courier';
                   break;
               default:
                   ? = 'Post Office';
                   break;
               }

         }
      });
});
```

I don't know how to get the right array key so I can change it, that's where I put the ?.

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do it this way:

```
$.each(data.data, function () {
    switch(this.Shipping) {
    case 1: 
        this.Shipping='PostNet';
        break;
    case 2: 
        this.Shipping='Courier';
        break;
    default: 
        this.Shipping='Post Office';
    }
});
```

Look at the console to see the updated object.

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tv7n1u1t/1/)

Answer (score 1):

You're close.

Loop through the `JSON object`. When key matches string, then make the `switch`. Once you match one of the values, change the parent loop value into the desired value.

Change your JS into this:

```
$.each(data.data, function (key, value) {    
    $.each(this, function(k, v) {
        if(k == 'Shipping') {
             switch(v) {
                    case 1:
                   value.Shipping = 'PostNet';
                   break;
                case 2:
                   value.Shipping = 'Courier';
                   break;
                default:
                   value.Shipping = 'Post Office';
                   break;
             }
        }
    });
});
```

**https://jsfiddle.net/zeopL56n/2/** (See console log)

Comment: God bless your soul... :) Thank you